# meson doesn't link library

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, meson-build

I'm tring to a fix a meson build not picking up on a link library. The `meson.build` file has

```py
tz_dep = dependency(
    'date',
    default_options : [ 'use_system_tzdb=true' ],
    fallback: [ 'date', 'tz_dep' ]
)

# ...

executable(
    'waybar',
    src_files,
    dependencies: [
        # ...
        tz_dep
    ],
    include_directories: [include_directories('include')],
    install: true,
)
```

and it does find `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/date/dateConfig.cmake`. The corresponding `dateTargets-none.cmake` is

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated CMake target import file for configuration "None".
#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Commands may need to know the format version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION 1)

# Import target "date::date-tz" for configuration "None"
set_property(TARGET date::date-tz APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS NONE)
set_target_properties(date::date-tz PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_NONE "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdate-tz.so.2.4.1"
  IMPORTED_SONAME_NONE "libdate-tz.so.2.4.1"
  )

list(APPEND _IMPORT_CHECK_TARGETS date::date-tz )
list(APPEND _IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_date::date-tz "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdate-tz.so.2.4.1" )

# Commands beyond this point should not need to know the version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION)
```

However, meson does not link `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdate-tz.so.2.4.1`.

I'm not sure if the problem is in meson or the cmake config. I can provide more details if required.

Comment: Can you verify the value of `${_IMPORT_PREFIX}` by adding a print statement to that file? `message(STATUS "_IMPORT_PREFIX: ${_IMPORT_PREFIX}")`

Comment: I don't have any meson experience, but it looks like you might need to tell meson you're dealing with a cmake dependency (https://mesonbuild.com/Dependencies.html#cmake).

Comment: @StephenNewell No, that's not it. It finds the package alright, include paths etc are accounted for. Adding `method = 'cmake'` doesn't change a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am wrinting an ebuild (gentoo package) for waybar right now and had the same issue you are describing. The solution is in your `meson.build` file, it specified the `date` dependency incomplete.

This is the patch i apply, and then it works (i have no clue about meson and stuff, but this seems makes `waybar` compile):

```
diff --git a/meson.build b/meson.build
index 5d45a29..dd56c29 100644
--- a/meson.build
+++ b/meson.build
@@ -98,7 +98,7 @@ gtk_layer_shell = dependency('gtk-layer-shell-0',
         required: get_option('gtk-layer-shell'),
         fallback : ['gtk-layer-shell', 'gtk_layer_shell_dep'])
 systemd = dependency('systemd', required: get_option('systemd'))
-tz_dep = dependency('date', default_options : [ 'use_system_tzdb=true' ], fallback: [ 'date', 'tz_dep' ])
+tz_dep = dependency('date', default_options : [ 'use_system_tzdb=true' ], modules : [ 'date::date', 'date::date-tz' ], fallback: [ 'date', 'tz_dep' ])

 prefix = get_option('prefix')
 sysconfdir = get_option('sysconfdir')
```

Maybe that helps!

Best Regards, Jonas